# How to debug Android App Connected to Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, debugging, keystore

I'm developing an app connected to native Facebook app. 
I found that Facebook requires a hashkey of my App in order to connect it to the Facebook native app. 
When I export my app using a keystore, there's no problem-I just have to register my hashkey on the facebook app setting console, and it works fine. 
However, when I debug my app, Native Facebook App recognizes my app as unregistered. I think this because Eclipse applies different keystore(the default debug keystore) on my app when debugging.

So I made two versions of my Facebook app on the server side-the real one, and the one for my debug-keystore.

I want my app to call the former one when released, and the letter one when debugging. 
Is there any way, in Android Java code, to check if the current app is running on the debug keystore?

Answer (score 2):

You can register both two hash key of on the facebook app setting console.
More than one hash key can be setup on a facebook app